# "Bind" socket to user

Tags: node.js, websocket, sails.js

I'm fairly new to sockets and wanted to give an existing application a few realtime elements, like notifications. I'm using SailsJS (and Passport with local strat) and wanted a service which can be called like

```
Notification.send(userID, message);
```

This would also be a pretty cool way for all other kinds of realtime events (private messages, ...). But what I need to know is how to "bind" a socket to a UserID.

Any ideas or articles (couldn't find anything on Google - probably because I don't know what exactly to search for...)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the pubsub hook enabled (it's enabled as long as you don't see pubsub: false) in your .sailsrc, You can have a client subscribe to their own user model like this so they will receive any notifications sent to their userId:

```
User.findOne(userId).then(function (me) {
    User.subscribe(req.socket, me, 'message');
})
```

Then you can call this to send notifications to a specific user in controllers:

```
User.message(recieverUserId, {type: "message", data: notification});
```

Just change type to whatever is relevant like type: "new Match" and send the appropriate data.
Edit: basically, .message() is the sails pubsub library's way of sending notifications to the subscribed Model.  you could also pass an array of users into User.subscribe